# Flash application in Jquery and Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, xml, ajax, flash

my first time posting here.
My question is as follow:
I need to build a horizontal scroller like the one in Itunes or like the one that the macs uses in the finder window.

http://www.flashcomponents.net/upload/samples/4250/index.html?full=true

The client, however wants this to be fed from an xml file and to display html content on the page once a certain thumb has been clicked. The html will get fed also from the xml file.
I was wondering if anybody could point me in the right direction. I know I can do this on flash and some PHP, but does anybody now if this can be accomplished through Jquery or Mootools and Ajax to load the content, will it be better to do it one way or another?. I figure this will be much convenient, yet again I am not an expert on Ajax and to tell you the truth I'm rather new to it.

Thanks,
Luis

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a "fisheye" control. There is an experimental dojo one, but I don't know if it meets your xml criteria. But you could probably overload the widget to handle that.

http://dojocampus.org/explorer/#Dojox_Widgets_FishEyeLite_Images

If that doesn't meet your needs, trying searching for fisheye and see if you can find anything that meets your needs.